# A function is continuous if it is linear

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be $\mathbb Q$-linear in the sense that $f(ax + by)= af(x) + bf(y)$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb Q$ and $x, y \in \mathbb R$. Suppose $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = L$. Show that $f$ is continuous at any $x_{0}$ $\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Shouldn't $L=0$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams We don't need to assume $L=0$ because we can deduce it: $L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(1/n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} f(1) = 0$.

Comment: @JairTaylor We don't even need the limit to do so since $f(2x) = 2f(x)$. Taking $x = 0$, we get $f(0) = 2f(0)$ so $f(0) = 0$. It's just odd that the problem would phrase it this way unless it wants you to make that realization on your own.

Comment: @CameronWilliams We don't yet know that $f$ is continuous, so knowing $f(0) = 0$ doesn't tell us $L = 0$.

Comment: Ohh yeah fair fair. You're right.

Comment: @JairTaylor quick note: that limit should be as $n \to \infty$

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Y. Dmp What did you try? Note that showing $\lim_{h \to 0} (f(a + h) - f(a)) = 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$ proves continuity.

Comment: But how to show *f* is continuous for all *x* $ \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: By the way, from the hypothesis we know that for any rational $q$ we have $f(q) = f(q\cdot 1 + 0\cdot 0) = qf(1) + 0f(0) = qf(1)$, and by the continuity result this implies that for any real $x$ and any rational sequence $q_n$ converging to $x$, we have $f(x) = \lim_{q_n \to x}f(q_n) = \lim_{q_n \to x}q_nf(1) = xf(1)$. Thus $f$ is linear with slope $f(1)$. Without the hypothesis that $f$ is continuous at some point, this is actually false if we accept the axiom of choice: see [discontinuous linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#A_nonconstructive_example)

Answer (score 2):

I just summarize the comments:

Thanks to  Jair Taylor we know that $L=0$ : $L = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(\frac{1}{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}f(1) = 0$.

Thanks to Pratyush Sarkar, for all $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{h\to0} (f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)) = \lim_{h\to0} (f(x_0)+f(h)-f(x_0)) = \lim_{h\to0} f(h) = 0.$

So $f$ is continuous at any $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment that $L=0$, now we let $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $p_{n}<r<q_{n}$, $p_{n},q_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $p_{n},q_{n}\rightarrow r$, then $p_{n}-r,q_{n}-r\rightarrow 0$ and hence $f(p_{n}-r),f(q_{n}-r)\rightarrow 0$. But $f(p_{n}-r)=f(p_{n})-f(r)$, similarly for $f(q_{n}-r)$, so $f(p_{n}),f(q_{n})\rightarrow f(r)$. This shows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow r^{-}}f(x)=f(r)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow r^{+}}f(x)=f(r)$, so $f$ is continuous at $r$.